# Socket.io vs net class in node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am reading about TCP connections for past few days ,I came across NET as a native nodejs library and socket.io ..can anyone suggest which one will be better with pros and cons of both

Comment: A much more useful question here would describe what you are trying to accomplish and list the requirements in a transport that you've determined are needed in order to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.io` is a specific message based protocol built on top of TCP.

If you want to send messages where you define a message name and send a payload for the message and the other side listens for a specific set of message names and you have a socket.io library already implemented for the other end of your connection, then socket.io will work great and will be a lot simpler to use and offer more ready-made capabilities (such as auto-reconnect).

If you intend to implement your own protocol, then you will use TCP in order to implement your own protocol.  If the type of data you are sending is not really message-based (such as audio/video streaming or large file uploads as a couple examples), then you will want to either use TCP or use some other protocol that is also built on top of TCP (such as HTTP, FTP, etc...).

As with any feature in a library, define your requirements, understand the options available in your system and find the solution that best matches your requirements.  Since you have said absolutely nothing about your requirements, we cannot make a specific recommendation.